# Using Linq to Entities and havign a NOT IN clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a SQL query that I am trying to convert to LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE LICENSE_RTK NOT IN(
SELECT KEY_VALUE  FROM TABLE2
WHERE REFERENCE_RTK    = 'FOO')
```

So I wrote one query for inner query and then one query for the outer one and used `Except`:

```
var insideQuery = (from pkcr in this.Repository.Context.TABLE2 where pkcr.Reference_RTK == "FOO" select pkcr.Key_Value);
var outerQuery = (from pl in this.Repository.Context.TABLE1 select pl).Except(insideQuery);
```

But this is wrong. Cannot even compile it. What is the correct way of writing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compile second query, because `Except` should be used on Queryables of same type. But you are trying to apply it on `Queryable<TABLE1>` and `Queryable<TypeOfTABLE2Key_Value>`. Also I think you should use `Contains` here:

```
var keys = from pkcr in this.Repository.Context.TABLE2 
           where pkcr.Reference_RTK == "FOO" 
           select pkcr.Key_Value;

var query = from pl in this.Repository.Context.TABLE1 
            where !keys.Contains(pl.License_RTK)
            select pl;
```

NOTE: Generated query will be `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`, but that's what you want

```
SELECT * FROM FROM [dbo].[TABLE1] AS [Extent1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
     FROM [dbo].[TABLE2] AS [Extent2]
     WHERE ([Extent2].[Reference_RTK] == @p0) AND 
           ([Extent2].[Key_Value] = [Extent1].[License_RTK]))
```